# What is the Headset icon on apps in dock on iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications, dock, headphones, ipados

I use ipad occasionally but today I came across a new "icon", which I have never seen before.

[image]

I have not connected any headphones to the iPad. So, what is the little "headset" icon on top of the app icon in the dock?

iPadOS: 14

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering the same. According to 3 Reddit threads this is a Siri App Suggestion based on having used the suggested app with headphones.

These are the threads:

https://old.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/bbjz1d/what_does_the_headphones_symbol_mean/

https://old.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/78j9k6/headphone_icon_in_docks_recent_apps/

https://old.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/74b74u/weird_dock_bug_when_using_headphone_jack_in_ios_11/

Answer (score 1):

This is a handoff suggestion from another device. Usually it’s a recommendation from an iPhone but I’ve seen it come from a Mac as well that had any sort of headphones attached. Could be AirPods or generic Bluetooth or wired headphones.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/hand-off-tasks-between-ipad-and-mac-ipad16784270/ipados

Siri settings can be relevant here as well:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/change-siri-settings-ipade5045bb1/ipados

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you were just listening to this app in background? Or using it on your mac?

Comment: No. I didn’t connect any headphones and no music is playing and all the apps are closed in the background

Comment: On your mac also?

Comment: Because i just thought that it could be from PC or a suggestion to open app **with** headphones...